# forcing clang to emit code for never-referenced static member function of class-template instantiation

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I can easily achieve this in `gcc` using the `used` and `noinline` [function attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) (see code below), but this doesn't work in `clang` even though it's supposed to support both of these function attributes.

**A simplified example:**

```
template<typename T>
struct Factory {
    static __attribute__((used, noinline))
    T createFoo() { return T(); }
};

int main() {
    Factory<int> f; // instantiate and use Factory<int>
}
```

Compile the code in `gcc` and use `nm` to confirm that gcc correctly emitted the function:

```
nm --demangle test | grep createFoo
0000000000403185 W Factory<int>::createFoo()
```

The code compiles fine in `clang`, but it does not emit code for the static `createFoo()` function like it's supposed to.

**How can I force clang to emit this static function which is never referenced?**

Comment: This behavior is outside the standard so no compiler is required to support it.  The portable solution would be to add a reference to the method.

Comment: @brianbeuning: I realize compilers aren't required to support it - my question is whether `clang` does or not. (It's supposed to, as `gcc` does, via the `used` function attribute, which tells the compiler to pretend that it was referenced somewhere.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### This is definitely a bug in clang.

As the OP stated in a comment, the semantics of `__attribute__((used))` is to treat the function as if it were *actually* referenced in the code, forcing it to emit code for the function, which clang is not doing in this case.

Furthermore, all class-member-functions have extern linkage as defined by C++. So when the class is instantiated, and the compiler (supporting gcc-style function attibutes) sees `__attribute__((used))` for the member function, it should know immediately that an externally visible definition of that function should be emitted. **gcc** is doing this, bug **clang** is not.

A temporary workaround (for clang) is to explicitly reference the function somewhere in your code.

You should also [file a clang bug report with llvm](http://llvm.org/bugs/) to get this issue fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation - I will go ahead and file a bug report.

Comment: So this is still a bug with Clang 10, huh

Comment: It seems to be still a bug in Clang 13 too.